# How to filter a large array of strings by an array of substrings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary, filter

I am using angular to filter a large collection of strings for an autocomplete field.
What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
largeArrayOfStrings = ['string1', 'string2', 'test one', 'one', 'two test', 'three', 'test one two', ...]
substring = [‘test’, ‘one’, ‘two’]

values = substringArray.map(h.includes)
// I would want values to be the following
values = ['test one two']
// That is the only string that contains all the strings from substring array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn `h` into a Set, which has constant lookup time:

```
  const toFilter = new Set(h);

  const result = substringArray.filter(el => toFilter.has(el));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it:

```js
const strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'test one', 'one', 'two test', 'three', 'test one two']
const subs = ['test', 'one', 'two']

const result = strings.filter(x => subs.every(y => x.includes(y)))

console.log(result)
```

Using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

The idea is to start with the filter of the words and to make sure for for `every` sub-string in your `subs` array you get a hit in the current word of the main array. That happens only for the `'test one two'` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have been writing a library to do things like this, and I found a quite easy solution to this very problem. The code is written originally in TypeScript, but I have converted it to JS:

```
const filterArray = (arr, toKeep) => {
    for (item of toKeep)
        arr = arr.filter(i => i = toKeep);

    return arr;
};
```

This goes to say that this function assumes that the array can have items in it other than strings, and if you want to ensure strings, just add this line at the beginning of the function:

```
for (arrIetm of arr) if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arrItem) != '[object String]' return;
```

By the way, if you want to check out the library, the GitHub is at this link:
https://railrunner16.me/raildash/

Best wishes, and good luck!